# Iniciar Windows Service automaticamente

Tags: c#, .net, windows-service

Criei um `Windows Service` de teste, andei pesquisando e vi que para iniciá-lo automaticamente é preciso mudar a propriedade `StartType` do objeto `serviceInstaller` para *Automatic*, que o serviço, depois de instalado, já inicia automaticamente. Entretanto, olhei no Gerenciamento do Computador na parte de Serviços e o Tipo de Inicialização do meu serviço está como Manual. Segue *prints* abaixo:

[image: SS]
Serviço no gerenciamento do Computador

[image: SS]
Configurações do serviceInstaller

**Código do ProjectInstaller.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace servico_teste
{
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class ProjectInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public ProjectInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        using (var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller1.ServiceName))
        {
            sc.Start();
        }
    }

    public void ServiceInstaller() 
    {
    //... Installer code here
    this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall);
    }
}
}
```

**Código do Service1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;


namespace servico_teste
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    Timer timer1;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        timer1 = new Timer(new TimerCallback(timer1_Tick), null, 15000, 60000);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        StreamWriter vWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\testeServico.txt", true); 
        vWriter.WriteLine("Servico Parado: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
        vWriter.Flush(); 
        vWriter.Close();

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender) 
    { 
        StreamWriter vWriter = new StreamWriter(@"c:\testeServico.txt", true);
        vWriter.WriteLine("Servico Rodando: " + DateTime.Now.ToString()); 
        vWriter.Flush(); 
        vWriter.Close(); 
    }
}
}
```

A pergunta é: como faço para que depois de instalado o serviço inicie automaticamente?

Comment: E você não pode mudar o **Serviço no gerenciamento do Computador** para automático?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Achei uma [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1042986/221800).

```
public ServiceInstaller() {
    //... Installer code here
    this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);
}

void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e) {
    using (var sc = new ServiceController(serviceInstaller.ServiceName)) {
         sc.Start();
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/StartService.cs).

Comment: Não resolveu, creio que eu esteja fazendo algo de errado. A linha `this.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);` na parte do `ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall` está com o erro: _The name 'ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall' does not exist in the current context_.Mudei para o nome do meu objeto `serviceInstaller1_AfterInstall` mas ainda assim o serviço não inicia automaticamente.

Comment: É para existir, ele está logo abaixo.

Comment: O problema era o nome mesmo. Contudo o serviço ainda está com o tipo de inicialização manual.

Comment: Tem algum problema no código, mas como você não postou ele, não tem como ajudar. tela do VS não ajuda nada.

Comment: Acrescentei os códigos na pergunta @bigown

Comment: Este trechos de código não mostram nada relevante para ajudar no que está falando. Por sinal a pergunta já foi respondida. Este parece ser outro problema. Quando for perguntar sobre ele especificamente, coloque o código que configura toda instalação (classe `ServiceInstaller`).